# How to protect querystring or parameters passed to another page

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a scenario which displays list of products in a tabular format and one of the column has a link to the product page.

```
<td> <a href="/ViewProduct/{{$request->prd_ID}}/{{$request->usr_ID}}" id="link" > Product </a> </td>
```

The route is as follows:

```
Route::get('ViewProduct/{pid?}/{uid?}', 'ViewProductController@Page_Load');
```

and the URL would be:

```
http://example.com/ViewProduct/11/4
```

This approach directly exposes the product id and user id and can be modified easily in the browser. Any inputs on how to address these concerns in php/laravel?

Comment: ...and the concern with exposing the product id and user id is what exactly...?

Comment: If you want to make URL parameters not readable URL parameters try encrypting them.However you cannot stop some one from modifying parameters.
EX:http://example.com/ViewProduct/Ac5td/3Cgt
Consider using POST var if you want to hide ID.

Comment: @DeshanR Don't use POST just for the purpose of "hiding" the id. Anyone who is savvy enough to want to manipulate URL parameters in the first place won't be deterred in the least by a POST request; yet using POST requests has many more implications and side effects.

Comment: @deceze Thats why i suggest him encrypting variable so they are not readble using POST method is as far as he can go to hide them better than using Url parameters in this specific case.Agree with you POST vars can be manipulated after all.

Comment: @deceze, these id's are primary keys of the respective tables, so someone can easily guess other product/user ids. Some places, edit option is available so it might pose a risk (i understand proper check is made before allowing someone to edit it).

Comment: @DeshanR, I will look into it. That seems to be a better option and including proper checks whenever edit mode is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not something you should worry about, it's a pointless waste of time. Somebody changes the URL from a `2` to a `3` and they'll see a different page... **so what?!** If they're allowed to see that page in the first place, i.e. if they could click around on your site and eventually discover this page, then what's the issue? They just took a shortcut. If they're *not* allowed to see that page... well, you're doing authorisation checks when someone is requesting that page, aren't you? If you are, then there's no issue at all. If you're not, then *that's* your real problem. Trying to keep URLs "secret" and "unguessable" is impossible, just do proper authorisation checks.

Comment: that's true and fair and the energy should go in ensuring the proper authorization. Thanks.